# How Would I Make This Test Data Driven?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I have several tests where the only thing which is different from them is the username and I would like to do `TestCase[]` with them but nothing seems to be working. Here is the test:

```
    [Test]
    public void SACCanSelectPayments()
    {
        LufasWebManager.OktaDevTenantSignIn(Users.lufas_sac1.ToString(), LufasWebManager.EncryptPassword(_site.GetAuditPassword(Users.lufas_sac1)));
        new MenuBarSubPage(LufasWebManager.Driver).SelectPracticeAudit(MenuBarSubPage.PracticeAuditOptions.WardOrBranch);
        LufasWebManager.Stall(2500);
        LufasWebManager.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//simple-snack-bar/div/button")).Click();
        var auditPage = new BaseAudit(LufasWebManager.Driver);
        auditPage.ClickContinue();
        auditPage.ClickContinue();
        var paymentsPage = new AuditAddPaymentsDepositsSubpage(LufasWebManager.Driver);
        SelectPayments(paymentsPage);
    }
```

The thing which needs to change is in the first line the `Users.lufas_sac1`. I have tried doing:

```
[TestCase("lufas_sac1")]
[Test]
public void SACCanSelectPayments(string user)
{
   LufasWebManager.OktaDevTenantSignIn(Users.user.ToString(), LufasWebManager.EncryptPassword(_site.GetAuditPassword(Users.user)));
   ...
}
```

That didn't work so I tried string interpolation and that didn't work either. I am just not sure how to go about making test cases with the various users so I am not duplicating tests.  Got to keep it DRY.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the `user` parameter in the test?

Comment: I tried using the `user` parameter and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Your example, at least as posted, doesn't use the parameter you are passing.

The name of the parameter is 'user'. It is passed to the method as a string. Your `TestCase` attribute, gives it the value "lufas_sac1", which I assume is the name of the user you want to use for the test.

OTOH, your code is passing in the name held in `Users.user`, converting it to a string. NUnit, of course, knows nothing abut your class `Users` and does nothing to initialize it.

If you change the first argument to the login call to simply 'user' then you will make use of the passed-in argument. However, I suspect you will need to make changes to the second login argument as well. Not enough info here about the `Users` class to suggest further changes.

BTW, as a matter of style, I'd drop the `Test` attribute when using `TestCase`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code, I cast my variable `user` as type `Users` and got it working.

```
    [TestCase(Users.lufas_sac1)]
    [Test]
    public void UserCanSelectPayment(Users user)
    
    {
        LufasWebManager.OktaDevTenantSignIn(user.ToString(), LufasWebManager.EncryptPassword(_site.GetAuditPassword(user)));
        new MenuBarSubPage(LufasWebManager.Driver).SelectPracticeAudit(MenuBarSubPage.PracticeAuditOptions.WardOrBranch);
        LufasWebManager.Stall(2500);
        LufasWebManager.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//simple-snack-bar/div/button")).Click();
        var auditPage = new BaseAudit(LufasWebManager.Driver);
        auditPage.ClickContinue();
        auditPage.ClickContinue();
        var paymentsPage = new AuditAddPaymentsDepositsSubpage(LufasWebManager.Driver);
        SelectPayments(paymentsPage);
    }
```